# Failed to load resource socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to use in socket.io in my node.js app, but my client can't get the library from my sever and I don't know why.

Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js status of 404 (Not Found)
Server site:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);

    app.use(express.static('public'));

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
    });

    app.listen(3000, function () {
      console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
    });

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
      console.log('a user connected');
    });
```

Client side:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Have you install socket.io on your project?

Comment: yes I have socket.io installed

Answer (score 1):

Your index.html code couldn't find socket.io because you are sendig only Index.html for response. Please try following code.

Use following code:

```
//"client" is folder for client code which contains index.html
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
```

Remove following code. Node.js will find index.html automatically.

```
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
});
```

Change your index.html
New code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>
```

Old code:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: The server-side socket.io library automatically exposes a route for the client side socket.io.js file.  If the server-side library is installed property with node.js, then this route will serve the file for you and it serves it from a directory buried in the node_modules hierarchy (something you don't have to worry about).  So, this answer does not solve the OP's issue in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why your code isn't working, but if socket.io is installed properly, then it automatically configures a route in Express to serve the request for `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.  So, apparently socket.io is not configured/installed properly in your situation.

I can tell you that this initialization of Express and socket.io works and does not have the problem you speak of:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(80);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my index.html while learning Node.js.
The console prompted similar error

I removed socket.io module by executing `npm r socket.io` in my project directory and re-installed it using `npm i socket.io` and then it worked fine.